# Conditional include a file in C

Tags: c, conditional-statements

I have a question. Supose that 2 teams makes modification on a source file that include a header "test.c" But one had that file called "test.C" and the another one had it called "test.c"
Is there a way to conditional include that file in C?
Something like:

```
#ifdef test.C
    #include "test.C"
#else
    #include "test.c"
#endif
```

Comment: Why don't you try that and see if it works?  Also, this is what source control is for, not conditional includes.  Make a branch (using git, it's quite easy), and have people make changes in different branches.

Comment: That sounds like a bad naming convention. I don't understand why you want it in this particular case (although there are reasons to want it), but the c preprocessor has no method to check if files exist. You could use a makefile or similar to define certain constants.

Comment: I think its time you should use some kind of [version control like SVN](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~vailen/svn_howto.htm)

Comment: ok, thanks a lot! I hoped that is a way to check what file exist. Yes, is a bad naming convention, but I have a project and I don't know with wich name my teacher will test the program and that's why I asked.

Answer (score 0):

As Dave correctly stated, *the c preprocessor has no method to check if files exist.* But provided with a suitable shell and a compiler which allows to define a macro on the command line, you can do something like

```
set test.?; cc source.c -DTEST=\"$1\"
```

and in the source file have

```
#include TEST
```